Chrome (Messenger, WhatsApp Web) always asking me for password, device link
Chrome constantly asks me to re-enter passwords (e.g., Messenger) and relink devices (e.g., WhatsApp Web).
A Chrome extension resets all its user preferences each time I open the browser.
Spotify on the desktop is experiencing similar issues, like bugging and not loading some playlist covers.
Could it be linked to me after manually clearing some files (using TreeSize) from the AppData folder on my Windows PC, I’m facing recurring issues with Chrome and certain desktop applications.
I didn’t delete anything from the Google folder, but the issues started right after clearing AppData. Could missing files or permissions be the cause or just a coincidence?
